# Why can't I format this as a currency?

Tags: google-sheets

Does anybody know why the currency format is not being applied to the highlighted column?

I'm using the following ImportJSON script from this gist https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Most likely it is a format issue. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1):

The currency format is not being applied because the values are text, not numbers. To fix this, there are several options:

1. set IMPORTJSON to return numbers or to return formatted text.
2. Use formulas to parse the values as the required type or to format them
3. Copy/paste as value only, then if necessary remove blank spaces, etc.